# Jenkins and maven multi module Projects missing artifacts

Tags: maven, maven-2, jenkins, multi-module

This is a simplified example of an ear project, the parent pom aggregates the EAR, the EJBs, and the jars.

I have this structure in a Maven project, stored in SVN:

```
parent/
|- pom.xml
|- modulA/
|  |- pom.xml
|- modulB/
|  |- pom.xml
```

modulB has a Dependency of modulA

The pom.xml have the modules section

```
<modules>
  <module>modulA</module>
  <module>modulB</module>
</modules>
```

And a Dependency Management section

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group</groupId>
            <artifactId>modulA</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group</groupId>
            <artifactId>modulB</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The sub-modules reference the parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>
```

in my PC when I compile for the first time with maven 2.2.1 (windows)

```
mvn clean compile
```

I don't have any problems

but.... when Jenkins try to compile for first time (Maven 2.2.1 Linux RedHat)

```
Missing:
----------
 1) modulA:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT

   Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

   Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=group -DartifactId=modulA -Dversion=0.0.2-   SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=group -DartifactId=modulA -Dversion=0.0.2-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

   Path to dependency: 
      1) modulB:ejb:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
 2) modulA:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT


   ----------
   1 required artifacts are missing.
```

Why????????

After that if I deploy the project from my pc to Artifactory, Jenkins doesn't have problems, because Jenkins downloads the artifact from the repository... but why does Jenkins depend on the artifacts in the repository?

:(

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT:**

I thought the dependencyManagement section only "defines" the dependencies, but if a submodule doesn't use the dependency, the dependency isn't added to the submodule.
I drop the dependencyManagement section and the problem in Jenkins still occurs.

It works on my PC without problems.

Comment: Is it possible to get an effective POM for one of the modules? If it works locally, it could be that the artifacts got deployed to the local repository as part of the development, before the problem got introduced, which would effectively hide it until you attempt to build on a new machine (such as the build machine)

Comment: If you clean out your local maven repository on your box does the build fail on your box the first time? I am guessing yes and if so  that means something in your build is referencing modulA-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar before it is built. Hard to say what that is without seeing more of your parent and module poms.

Answer (score 0):

I hope above dependency management section is inside the parent pom. According to your requirement modulB has a Dependency of modulA. So I suggest you to include dependency in moduleB instead of having it in the parent pom. I think when it runs in first time maven is looking for both dependencies since you have mentioned in in the parent pom.Look at your project build order. First it builds module A and then B. In your case I hope you have include all other dependencies in moduleA's pom file and once it built it will deploy a jar file in to m2 repository. And then moduleB start to build and since your dependency is already in the m2 repository it wont shout and project will build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you build parent project, your Jenkins user's maven repository won't have modulA installed.  `clean compile` is then run successfully in modulA, but nothing is installed.  When it is run in modulB, the dependency on modulA can't be resolved.

If your Jenkins job's goal was `clean install` instead of `clean compile`, then modulA's artifacts would be installed to the Jenkins user's repository before the modulB build begins, and all would work.

Presumably this worked on your own machine because either you had run `mvn install` at least once in modulA, or because your IDE's classpath resolved the problem for you.